# Android Studio doesn't recognize the addView method

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application in Android Studio (Giraffe), written in Java, to which I need to add buttons to a ScrollView. I've done some research and found that the addView method is likely what I'd want to use. However, for some reason, my Android Studio does not recognize it as a method for the ViewGroup class. For instance, when I put the following:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.view.View;


class Test {
    ViewGroup.addView(someView);
}
```

It acts as though addView isn't a valid method, giving me the message of "Cannot resolve symbol 'addView'". Also, when being applied to an instantiated ScrollView, it reads as "Cannot resolve method 'addView' in 'View'".

Would anyone know why this is? From what I've read online, nobody else really seems to have this issue. I've already attempted a few troubleshooting steps- like rebuilding, restarting, and even reinstalling Android Studio, but I haven't gotten any results. I'd really appreciate any feedback.

Edit: Here is a functional example of code that produces the same error.

```
class Test {
    public static void someMethod() {
        View someView = null;
        ViewGroup.addView(someView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your code is not valid Java. Method calls must be inside a method, constructor or (static) initializer block. You cannot have method calls directly inside a class body in Java.

Comment: Actually running the code isn't the issue, it's that the method isn't recognized by Android Studio.  So, I don't really think reproducible code would help here.

Comment: The code that you are using is **exactly the same** that is in the question?

Comment: Even within a method, I still get the same result. To clarify, when hovering over the text of ".addView()", I cannot even see the documentation for it with CTRL+Q. It doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Use an instance of ViewGroup to assure it works

Comment: Thanks, Cmak. This works. I should be able to figure it out from here.